# How to properly animate re-arrangement of children in a GridView?

Tags: android, gridview, android-animation

I'm creating an app which uses a GridView backed with a cursor adapter, where the user can add or remove items. Everything works properly, except for the child re-arrangement animation.

After deleting an item, the underlying data set changes and the gridview updates its childs. But they simply appear instantly. How do I animate their changes like the Google Keep app does?

Also, why on Earth does Google not care about UX? How hard is it for them to add this functionality to adapter based views?

Answer (score 0):

**Try putting below line in your layout:**

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

Comment: This doesn't to adapter based views and works only in normal `ViewGroups`